# ¿Deberíamos unificar las etiquetas [cast], [casting] y [conversión-de-tipos]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hay tres etiquetas: [cast](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cast) con 31 preguntas relacionadas, [casting](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casting) con 15 y [conversión-de-tipos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conversi%c3%b3n-de-tipos) con 53 preguntas.

[cast](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cast) se [define como](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/cast/info):

> se refiere a la transformación de un tipo de dato en otro. Esto se
>   hace para tomar las ventajas que pueda ofrecer el tipo a que se va a
>   convertir. Por ejemplo, los valores de un conjunto más limitado, como
>   números enteros, se pueden almacenar en un formato más compacto y más
>   tarde convertidos a un formato diferente que permita las operaciones
>   que anteriormente no eran posibles, tales como la división con
>   decimales.

[casting](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casting) se [define como](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/casting/info):

> Casting se refiere a la conversion de tipos ya sea explicita o
>   implícita.

[conversión-de-tipos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conversi%c3%b3n-de-tipos) se [define como](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/conversi%C3%B3n-de-tipos/info):

> Tipo de conversión es el camino de forma implícita o explícita el
>   cambio de una entidad (variable) de un tipo de datos a otro. Esto se
>   hace para aprovechar ciertas características de las jerarquías de tipo
>   o representaciones de tipo en diferentes lenguajes de programación.

¿Deberíamos unificar estas etiquetas? Y de ser así, ¿cuál créeis que debería prevalecer?

Comment: ¡Bien descubierto! ¿Y no podríamos hacer que ambas apuntaran a algo así como [tag:conversión-de-tipos], que ya existe? Se abre el casting de opciones... :D

Comment: A challenger appears! Gracias @fedorqui, lo he añadido a la pregunta ;-)

Comment: Nótese que cuando se hacen sinónimas, no desaparecen. Simplemente cuando empiezas a teclar "cas..." te sugeriría "conversión-de-tipos". Haz una prueba: ve a editar las etiquetas de esta pregunta y empieza a poner "featu..." de [meta-tag:feature-request]. Te sugerirá [meta-tag:petición-de-funcionalidad]. Y lo mismo si buscas en la [página de Etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags): te aparecerá y al clicar en ella te dirigirá a la etiqueta "madre". Más info en [Privilegios - crear sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, no sabía esto de los sinónimos

Comment: Yo mejoraria conversion de tipos, y las haria todas sinonimos de la version en español.. pero obviamente queda a votacion del publico...

Comment: Yo también voto por la versión más castiza. Que se esté usando y tenga el mayor número de preguntas habla bien de su incorporación al habla

Comment: esto se quedó en el limbo... @gbianchi ¿los moderadores lo habéis considerado?